# apt purge not working with regex on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04

I am trying to remove all the `nvidia` packages from my system using regex. But it gives me an error:

```bsh
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-*
```

Here's the command I am running:

```bsh
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or this simply isn't supported anymore. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I changed it to `sudo apt purge '?name(nvidia-*)'` and it's working! You can post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: Be sure to read the proposed removals carefully before agreeing. A poorly chosen wildcard can remove big slabs of your system.